# Redirecting old .aspx files to Wordpress equivalents

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, redirect

I've converted an associates old website to Wordpress.  The domain name remains the same.  All the old .aspx files fall into the root of the domain folder (www.xxx.com) with no .htaccess file  while the Wordpress replacement site has an .htaccess file - domain is www.xxx.com/ctpc

I have 36 old .aspx files in the root that I need to permanently redirect to the respective wordpress documents in the /ctpc subfoler.

I can do a little bit of code, html in particular and with good instructions can paste code, but writing code to get this done is obviously over my head.

I've researched this for a day and half now and am going downhill if any direction at all.  I'd be grateful for any help possible.

thank you,
~Jennifer

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend putting a .htaccess file in the root domain, with a redirect for each of the 36 .aspx files, like this:

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage1.aspx http://www.newsite.com/ctpc/newpage
```

Put one of those on each line for each of the .aspx files.  Do this in a text editor, like Notepad for Windows, save it as .htaccess, and then upload it to the root domain.

Comment: thank you and even though you have said I do not need any other code, I noticed in most .htaccess files I've looked at as a point of reference, there is a #Begin  and #End - are those necessary?

Comment: You can include those if you want, but they're not required.  I've never used them.

Answer (score 1):

There's a WordPress [redirection plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) that would allow you to manage all of this from within the WordPress admin section.  You can create redirects for all of your 36 pages and then keep track of how many time the pages are getting referenced and which pages still have old links.

Comment: I tried this but it seems aspx page still tries to load. the redirection plugin doesn't work. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using permalinks in Wordpress, put the 301 redirect that is listed above the Wordpress rewriting in your .htaccess file. And edit your .htaccess file yourself; if you let Wordpress automatically write to your .htaccess file, sometimes you'll end up with multiple rewrite entries that can cause problems.

Comment: Permalinks in Wordpress are how you get "pretty" urls, such as mysite.com/mypagename  instead of mysite.com/?page=id124

Those pretty permalinks are handled by the .htaccess file, so you might have to be careful how you edit the .htaccess file....

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Redirections Plugin

```
Under Add new redirection, put the following:

Source URL: /(.*).aspx
Regular expression: checked ☑ OR Select "REGEX" after Source URL
Target URL: /$1/
```

Answer (score -1):

One solution may be to add a META refresh tag to the header section of each of the .ASPX files that you need to redirect.

For example:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://www.xxx.com/ctpc/new-file">
...
```

This tag says to *refresh* the page in **5** seconds by sending the user to **www.xxx.com/ctpc/new-file**.  You can make this an immediate refresh by changing the time to **0**.

Comment: I did this and then found out that google will penalize my associates pages as spam

Comment: Please don't ever do this. SEOs will be crying, if you do :-(